# Background of my custom button isn't transparent

Tags: android, xml, button

I created a custom button and I saved it as a .png with a transparant background.
this is the code in xml

```
<Button
       android:id="@+id/btnReport"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:drawableTop="@drawable/report" />
```

and when i run it in the emulator I get my button with a grey background
(I cannot post images yet, because my reputation is too low. Apologies for this)
How do I make the background transparant?

Thanks.

Vincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing

```
android:background="@drawable/report"
```

Answer (score 0):

is that image "report" only transparent? You don´t need to set a transparent image, just set

```
  android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

to your button.